# Wireless G/Wireless N/and ATA/wired ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, networking

I have cat 5e wired throughout the house terminating in the basement right beside the incoming internet cable modem. This would be a great place to put a Gigabit wireless N router, however, when I place the router in that area the wireless (N) portion of the router doesn't work that well. I believe its because I get interference from my neighbours wireless router (g) and that router is location above basement grade but about 10 feet from my router. In fact, whenever I do a wireless network search in windows my neighbours router shows stronger strength.

To solve the problem I placed my router in the middle of my house on the second floor. Now the wireless portion works great, but then I don't have access to my wired part of the network. I also had to put my ata router right behind the wireless router on the second floor.  The best solution I think I could have would be to have 1 wired gigabit router in the basement to terminate the cat 5e cables and 1 wireless router in the middle of the house on the second floor,  but I cannot find a wired gigabit router. Any solutions on how to fix this problem? Should I by two wireless routers and turn the wireless portion off on one of the routers? Or is there a way to improve the wireless N performance so that it works well.

Comment: What wireless router do you have?

Comment: Well I have had a number of them. They all experienced roughtly the same problem. (Linksys, DLink, and belnik). Right now I connected back my old Dlink Wireless G back in on the second floor since it was working the best. But I in the last round I was using the Linksys wrt310N. Also the ATA us a Linksys as well

Answer (score 5):

Can you change the channel of your Wireless? changing the number to a non overlapping channel number should allow both wireless routers to co-exist in peace!

[image]

Comment: +1 Good idea.  Have seen the channel issue many times.  Quick survey will identify (netstumbler or similar)

Comment: Actually, I went up and down the channels ... trying to find one that work best. Pain in the ass, since I have 4 laptops....but none of them really fixed the problem. I'm keep wondering why my neighbours keeps coming in stronger. It seems to be a linksys....g

Comment: ... You shouldn't need to make a single change on the laptop, you just need to set the channel on the router then the laptops should be able to connect. Looking at this chart, I would personally try channels 1, 6 and 13 as then you should be guaranteed one that does not interfere at all with a neighbour... of course, it is possible someone else has WIFI with the SSID hidden? :S just throwing a possibility!

Comment: Okay, Just did a quick look at my neighbourhood. My Neighbour who is giving me the most problem is running a Linksys (bgn) on channel 1 with a speed of 130 (Strongest signal strenght) My other neighbour is is also using a Linksys (bgn) on Channel 11 with a speed of 130. (Less signal strength than me). So I'm wedged between two N networks one on channel 1 and the other on 11. Outside that I see at least 8 other networks mostly g but on various channels. (These all have less signal strength.)

Comment: Most of the networks are on channels 1, 6, and 11.

Comment: So, I change my channel to 8 and you can see me wedges between H and L who are my neighbors. I'm "r" 

Network Name      Signal Strength  Wireless Mode     Channel

H                   95%             802.11n           1
R                   62%             802.11g           8
L                   45%             802.11n           11

Seems my Neighbour 'H" has a really good signal.

Comment: Network  Signal Strength Wireless Mode Channel
H 95% 801.11n 1
R (me) 62% 802.11g 8
L 37% 802.11n 11

Answer (score 0):

Linksys makes a wirelss N router Full specs are here [WRT310N](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/CA/en/products/WRT310N)